# Crazy virtual onscreen keyboard on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, qt, touchscreen

I am on Kubuntu with a 2:1 laptop. Everything works apart the default on-screen keyboard. It appears when I click inside some document with the mouse, not with my fingers. It is getting really really annoying. The fact is that I have not found any way to disable it. It basically does not exist in the system settings.

Just to let you understand, the virtual keyboard I am speaking about is the default KDE one, the one based on Qt. (just google Qt virtual keyboard).

Any idea on how I can disable it ? or where the settings can be found?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: a screenshot follows:
[image]

No idea why it is grey in the screenshot, it usually is darker.
Like this: [image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of this "virtual onscreen keyboard"?

Answer (score 0):

The QT_IM_MODULE env variable contained the qt keyboard.. that was the problem. I just removed it from .bashrc